# accessing images in nsmutablearray xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3, parse-framework

I am converting individual images into UIImagePNGRepresentation but I keep getting a thread breakpoin ate let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(tile as! UIImage)! ImageNameList is an nsmutablearray of images

```
var imageNameList: [String] {
    var imageNameList2:[String] = [] //[NSMutableArray]()
    for i in 0...149 {
        let imageName = String(format: "pic_%03d", Int(i))
        imageNameList2.append(imageName)
    }
    return imageNameList2
}

let table = PFObject(className: "Cool")
        let tilesPF = imageNameList.map({ tile in
            let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(tile)! //cannot convert type string to type uiimage
            let file = PFFile(data: data)

            let tile = PFObject(className: "RealCool")
            tile["tile"] = file
        })
```

Comment: something in obj-c   `PFFile *theImageData = theUser[@"profilePic"];`

Comment: [theImageData getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
 }];

Comment: tryout this in the swift

Answer (score 0):

`UIImage` is not a subclass of `PFObject`, so the cast `tile as! UIImage` can never be successful. The Swift compiler should already be giving you a warning: “Cast from 'PFObject' to unrelated type 'UIImage' always fails”.

Comment: how can I fix it. could you please make an edit to show a way to fix it

Comment: what do you think

Comment: what do you think

Comment: Now you're trying to treat a string as an image. Why?

Comment: i have a bunch of images in a nsmutable array and I'm trying to save the array to my server but i first have to access each index or image in the string(nsmutablearray)

Comment: could you show me how to do that because I've been at this for two hours and I'm lost

Comment: I don't see any `NSMutableArray` in your question. I see a comment that contains the word `NSMutableArray`, but that is not the same thing as an actual `NSMutableArray`. I also see no instances of `UIImage` or any other image type in your question.